# Assert only if an entire word is filled out

Tags: python

```
string1 = "Billie Jean"
string2 = " "
teststring = string2.split(" ")
    for word in teststring:
        if word in string1:
            return True
    return False
```

Can I make it so that if string2 is for example: "Baby Jean" it's true, but if it's: "ea" it returns as false?

Comment: What do you mean by "an entire word"? For example what if `string2 = 'aby ean'` or if `string2 = 'Bab Jea'`?

Comment: `string2 = " "; teststring = string2.split(" ")` -- what do you expect `teststring` to be after this code?

Comment: You cannot give a rule by an example, you have to explain with words what is the rule you want to implement. Or at least give more examples for  other people can guess the rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the resolution is to split up `string1` into a list of words before performing an `in` check, as follows:

```py
string1 = "Billie Jean"
string2 = " "
string3 = 'Baby Jean'

words1 = string1.split()

def check(string):
    teststring = string.split()
    for word in teststring:
        # Notice that we iterate over a list of words instead of string1
        if word in words1:
            return True
    return False

print(check(string2))
print(check(string3))
```

Another option would be to use the [`set.intersection`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/intersection) method, which returns true if there are any shared elements between two collections (one of which is a `set`):

```py
string1 = "Billie Jean"
string2 = " "
string3 = 'Baby Jean'

words1 = set(string1.split())

def check(string):
    return True if words1.intersection(string.split()) else False

print(check(string2))
print(check(string3))
```

Outputs:

```py
False
True
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of pointers:

- `split()` by default splits on the `" "` character so you don't need to explicitly pass it.
- Since you are checking for word being in another string, you must split `string1` too.

Check the code below:

```
def func(string1, string2):
    for word in string2.split():
        if word in string1.split():
            return True
    return False

print(func("Billie Jean", "Baby Jean")) # True
print(func("Billie Jean", "ea")) # False
```

A more interesting solution would be the following:

```
def func(string1, string2):
    # create set of words for each string and see if intersection is empty or not
    return True if set(string1.split()) & set(string2.split()) else False

print(func("Billie Jean", "Baby Jean"))
print(func("Billie Jean", "ea"))
```

Since matching using the intersection of sets leverages hashing, this method will be a lot faster at scale. (Might not really matter to you know, but it is good to know)

PS. You might want to convert both strings to the same case (lower or upper) if you wish to match `"Jean"` with `"jean"`.